# Sad oneshot manga where a man helps a woman commit suicide again and again because she keeps coming back to life

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm trying to find this manga about an immortal woman who has already lived a long life thus she tries to commit suicide on a daily basis. She has someone who assists her to commit suicide: a young guy. The story started while he was strangling her to death while he is crying and saying something, I forgot what, probably don't leave or something cringey. But after she died she came back to life again and started getting mad at him because he's noisy like s child who lost someone but he became happy again like nothing happened after she told her to stop crying.

Anyway the ending was the girl having her body dismantled into a firework's powder then got shot and exploded to a lot of pieces which took her years to comeback to life again. She went back home and asked someone about the dude who used to assist her in committing suicide and the man who was asked said that he committed suicide because he lost his girlfriend and of course after knowing that the girl called him a dummy or something.

Comment: This is a really good description. If you remember anything else though, for example, roughly when you read it, don't hesitate to [edit] those details into your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [Usagi ga Nihiki](https://myanimelist.net/manga/111318/Usagi_ga_Nihiki), aka "A pair of bunnies".

> Suzu: looks to be in her twenties; actually an immortal who has lived for 398 years. Usami Sakurou: looks like a 19-year-old; actually is a 19-year-old who helps his lover to commit suicide daily. [(src)](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/usagi-ga-nihiki)

The synopsis is a perfect match for the question. The events of the first chapter are also pretty much exactly as described. It opens with the man strangling her (it doesn't work). The first chapter ends with her body ground up into powder and launched in a firework. It doesn't work, but it takes her years to reassemble, and by the time she returns to her home, Sakurou has already died.

There are two volumes, but only the first chapter was fan-translated. It is not officially licensed in English. According to MAL, there is also an original comic on the author's pixiv, available [here](https://www.pixiv.net/user/172214/series/11550). I don't believe it is translated.

Found by searching mangaupdates for the tags "suicide/s" and "immortal/s"